# Why am i getting this error: "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this"?

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

My goal is to show a notification ballon in 5 seconds. I am using [Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf](http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon) Library and following [this](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/36468/wpf-notifyicon#events) tutorial

**Demo Code**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            new Timer(_ => ShowBallon(), null, 0, 1000 * 5);
        }

        private void ShowBallon()
        {
            string title = "WPF NotifyIcon";
            string text = "This is a standard balloon";
            new TaskbarIcon().ShowBalloonTip(title, text, BalloonIcon.None); //Error is thrown in this line
        }
}
```

**Error Message**

[image]

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message?  The message is pretty straightforward about what is wrong, and what you need to change for the program to work.

Comment: @Servy I am no expert at c#. What am i supposed to do?

Comment: Did you read the error message?  It tells you exactly why your code isn't working.  You don't need to be an expert in C#.  It's telling you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: @Servy I guess i dont get the message. Can i solve this?

Comment: *Insert the line* [STAThread] *before* public partial class MainWindow : Window. However, I don't think that you would have had this error if you used a  System.Windows.Forms.Timer (or a WPF DispatcherTimer) rather than a System.Timer.

Comment: @Graffito, isn't [STAThread] only applicable to methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this exception because the `Timer` callback is executed in a thread pool thread that doesn't have `ApartmentState.STA`, which is required for creating WPF UI elements.

Better use the `DispatcherTimer` class, which has a `Tick` event that is fired in the UI thread.

Use it like shown below for a single shot action. If you actually intended to execute the `Tick` handler periodically, just remove the `Stop()` statement.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };
    timer.Tick += ShowBallon;
    timer.Start();
}

private void ShowBallon(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((DispatcherTimer)sender).Stop();

    string title = "WPF NotifyIcon";
    string text = "This is a standard balloon";
    new TaskbarIcon().ShowBalloonTip(title, text, BalloonIcon.None);
}
```